# How to make page i18n in Django right?

Tags: django, model, internationalization, django-hvad

Is there any module or right way to make simple multilingual pages in Django?

Should I use some model pattern? Or I can make it the way I want? Is django-multilingual still actual?

For example here's my model

```
class Page(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateField()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I need to use some apps to make it the right way.
Django-multilingual isn't under development now (it even doesn't works with current Django vesion).

So, I've found two packages, which meet my needs. It was django-hvad and django-modeltranslation, but django-hvad is still aplha and has some troubles ([like this](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad/issues/60)), so I chose django-modeltranslation.